# How do I find number of times a name has been repeated in a list?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I wrote a code for finding how many times a name is repeated in an array, there is some issue with it.

I need this to be done without any kind of collections framework (Maps, Set or Array) and only targeting to solve this by loops only.

```
package string;
import java.util.*;
public class CountingNames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i,j,t,c;
        String a[]=new String[10];
        String b[]=new String[10];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextLine();
            b[i]=a[i];
        }
        int len=b.length;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            c=1; //Setting Counter
            for(j=i+1;j<len-1;j++)
            {
                if(b[i].equals(b[j]))
                {
                    c++;
                    for(t=j;t<len-1;t++)
                    {
//Deleting the repeated element by replacing with the next element
                        b[t]=b[t+1];
                    }
                }
            }
             System.out.println(b[i]+" is repeated "+ c +" times ");
             len-=c-1; //Decreasing the loop by the number of times the element has been repeadted
       }
   }

}
```

INPUT:

```
HAROLD
HAROLD
HAROLD
JAVA
JOKER
HOLD
JAVA
KOI
JAVA
GOAT
```

OUTPUT:

```
HAROLD is repeated 2 times 
HAROLD is repeated 1 times 
JAVA is repeated 3 times 
JOKER is repeated 1 times 
HOLD is repeated 1 times 
KOI is repeated 1 times 
GOAT is repeated 1 times
```

Comment: Just a hint: separate INPUT from processing. The code you wrote requires that every time you want to test ... you have to enter the names manually. Dont do that. Start with a hardcoded array, and have your code work with that. Only when the processing seems to  work, *then* replace the hardcoded data with manual input. And: class names in Java go CamelCase, always. So call your class like `CountingExample` ...

Comment: And: i and j are okay for loop indexes, but for anything else: use names that mean something to the reader. t and c ... mean nothing. Dont do that. Dont think it is clever to save 1 second while typing - you pay for that every time you come back and try to read and understand your code. Write your code so that HUMANS can understand it!

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks I'll keep it in mind next time.

Comment: And variables and methods start with a lower case letter. These conventions make it easier for programmers to read the code, which makes it easier to debug. People will be more likely to help you if you edit the question with these sorts of changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single array and a hash map to find the number of times the items are repeated.
In the below solution, I loop over the String array 'a' once and populate a HashMap with the String value and then I either calculate the value by incrementing it, or I assign it the value of 1.
I can then loop over the HashMap key set (all the string values) and then print out their values which will be ht number of times they are repeated.

```
Map<String, Integer> mapOfNames = new HashMap<>();
        for(String s: a){
            if(mapOfNames.containsKey(s)){
                mapOfNames.put(s, mapOfNames.get(s) + 1);
            }
            else{
                mapOfNames.put(s, 1);
            }
        }

        for(String s : mapOfNames.keySet()){
            System.out.println(s + " is repeated " + mapOfNames.get(s) + " times.");
        }
```

Will print:

```
JAVA is repeated 3 times.
JOKER is repeated 1 times.
KOI is repeated 1 times.
HAROLD is repeated 3 times.
GOAT is repeated 1 times.
HOLD is repeated 1 times.
```

Comment: Thanks I get this but I'm trying to do it without using collections.

Comment: Why? Then your best attempt is do create a class like Map yourself.

Comment: @Milgo Probably because their assignment says so. And "best" attempt is subjective. Creating a map adds a ton of things that having to do with solving the problem at hand. This is a learning exercise. It is **perfectly** okay to try to solve it with basic means. You see, that is actually one of the challenges here: getting the looping right, so that you actually, without a map, identify the duplicates correctly, and count them as needed. Be careful about telling people "do not learn such things, use a convenient library call".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, some general tips: Avoid declaring several variables in one line. This doesn't help readability.

Secondly, please always provide significant names to your variables, especially if you intend to get help from other people. We cannot tell what a variable named `p` is supposed to do. i and j are OK to indicate index, but for anything else, use significant names.

Lastly, it is a bad practice to declare iterators outside of for loops. Always try to declare and initialize your iterator variables inside the for loop. This will avoid many headaches when your code is large and you won't lose track of something like `i`.

Now, your code could use some further refactoring. A second array is totally unnecessary.

```
public class CountWords {
   public static void calculate(){
            
      String a[]=new String[10];
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
      {
           System.out.println("Enter word: ");
           a[i]=sc.nextLine();
      }
            
      for(int i=0;i< a.length; i++)
      {
         int count = 1;
         /*rather than having a 2nd array, we can simply 
         have a nested for loop where the index starts at 1.
         you'll always be comparing the current element with the         
         next one.
         */
         for(int j = 1;j< a.length;j++)
         {
           if(a[i].equals(a[j]))
           {
            count++;
           }
         }
         System.out.println(a[i]+" is repeated "+ count +" times ");
       }
   }
  

}
```

Keep in mind that this will print the results repeated, that is to say, an input of
`HAROLD` * 3 will result in the output being
`"COUNT FOR HAROLD IS 3"` printed three times.

If you wish to strictly count the amount of times a word is ***repeated***, that is, we don't care about its first occurrence, then initialize `count` to 0 rather than 1.

This is not an ideal use for arrays. If there is no actual reason preventing you from using collections, you should absolutely use a HashMap for this type of problems to avoid the re-print of values.

As a ***possible*** workaround, you may try adding another for loop at the beginning, to count the unique words you have in your array. Store the amount in an `int` variable, then, create a new array with the size of that variable, and instead of printing into the console, add the word count result to a string, then proceed to insert that string into the uniqueWords array, using similar logic to NOT insert the count message if its already present in the uniqueWords array.
Lastly, iterate through this uniqueWords array to print its elements.

As to why your code failed:
In your T for loop, You were reassigning the items in your B array to be the next element.

So, it worked twice for Harold because B[t] was Harold, and B[t+1] was Harold as well.
But for the third iteration, B[t] is Harold and B[t+1] is Java.
Therefore, only one instance of Harold was found and the previous Harolds had been overwritten by the reassignment.

Comment: I used second array because I didn't wanted my first array to be altered when I was deleting the repeated name in my array.

Comment: @GhostCat You're right! My apologies, as I had simply copy and pasted the code into my IDE to refactor it, then I just pasted it back in a rush and didn't look much to the indentation. I've edited my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: @DOBBIE I understand what you were trying to do, but it is not an optimal approach. If this is for a university project, unless there's a specific requirement to not print the excessive calls, I would leave it as it is since it is very unlikely your professor will punish you for it. The fact that they're only letting you use arrays and not collections tells me that it is most likely an introductory course, and as such they probably won't be as strict about such a minor detail. If they did give you the requisite not to print that, try the workaround I mentioned at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping, you can use Map like below

```
//Assuming you have array "names" containing names
String[] names = new String[10];
Map<String,Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
     
     if(countMap.get(names[i]) != null)
         countMap.put(names[i],countMap.get(names[i])+1);
     else
         countMap.put(names[i],1);
 }
//Print your frequencies

for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : countMap.entrySet()) {
     
     System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" is repeated "+entry.getValue()+ " times.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks I get this but I'm trying to do it without using collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i,j;
        String a[]=new String[10];
        boolean b[]=new boolean[10];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        for(i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
            System.out.print(">>>");
            a[i]=sc.nextLine();
            b[i]=false;
        }

        for(i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
            int count = 0;

            if (!b[i]) {
                for(j=0 ; j<10 ; j++ ) {
                    if (a[i].equals(a[j])) {
                        count++;
                        b[j]=true;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(a[i] + " is repeated " + (count-1) + " times" );
                // If you need the number of times the name appeared then use the below line
                // System.out.println(a[i] + " is repeated " + (count) + " times" );
            }
        }
   }
}
```

If you need the number of times the name appeared in the list the use

`System.out.println(a[i] + " is repeated " + (count) + " times" );`

Or if you want the number of time the name is repeated, then use

`System.out.println(a[i] + " is repeated " + (count-1) + " times" );`

Input:-

```
HAROLD
HAROLD
HAROLD
JAVA
JOKER
HOLD
JAVA
KOI
JAVA
GOAT
```

Output:-

```
HAROLD is repeated 2 times
JAVA is repeated 2 times
JOKER is repeated 0 times
HOLD is repeated 0 times
KOI is repeated 0 times
GOAT is repeated 0 times
```